# How to fix : Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to make a dynamic dependent dropdown selection , so i got this error in the console when i try to ckeck if the function work or not !

I'am using laravel , ajax , jquery in this project

Also , when i delete the script of the dynamic dropdown box , the error stay 
Hope that you can help me 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this has to do with location of your

```
<script src="something"></script>
```

make sure you don't have same cdn and make your your link goes before script 
something like

```
<link></link>
<script></script>
```

All the link should go before script sentence